# Play (Scala) Custom form type validation

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In my view, I'm creating a radio buttons, with the values 0,1,2 (string).

```
inputRadioGroup(
  dayForm("time"),
  options("0"->"Morning","1"->"Afternoon","2"->"Night"))
```

In my model the I'm using time as a integer value, and radiobox does not have the option to submit the input as an integer.

So in my controller I though of converting the time input into a integer and checking if the value is between 0-2.

```
val dayForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "id" -> optional(longNumber),
    "time" -> <what can I  do here to avoid type mismatch?>,
    "date" -> sqlDate("yyyy-MM-dd") (Entry.apply)(Entry.unapply)
```

Is there a way to convert the time into a int and THEN verify if its a number between 0-2? Like this:

```
"time" -> number (min =0, max =2)
```

That one will result in the form not validating as the input string hasn't been converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write

```
val dayForm = Form(
    mapping(
    "id" -> optional(longNumber),
    "time" -> number (min =0, max =2),
    "date" -> sqlDate("yyyy-MM-dd")
    )((id, time, date) => Entry(id, convertFunction(time), date))
    ((entry: Entry) => Some(entry.id, inverseFunction(entry.time), entry.date))
)
```